# Use Apple's usdzconvert on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, macos

I've successfully built [Pixar's USD pipeline](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD) on a Linux VM, and I now strive to accomplish something similar to Apple's usdzconvert from their [USDZ tools](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/tools/).

As of right now, I'm able to run the standard commands from Pixar, such as [usdCat](https://graphics.pixar.com/usd/docs/USD-Toolset.html#USDToolset-usdcat), but what I'm missing is an executable that can convert certain formats (such as FBX or USDC) to `.usdz`. Is it possible in some way to import certain files/executables from Apple's tools and use them on my Linux VM? If so, how do I proceed?

Any other tips on how to convert to USDZ (using command line) are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use Apple's `usdzconvert` on linux. You need to:

1. Build USD to your system (which you already did)
2. Download Apple's [USDPython](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=USDPython) tools
3. Replace `usdpython/USD/lib` with the `USD/lib` you built
4. You may need to add `usdpython/USD/lib/python` to your `PYTHONPATH`, however, I'm not sure that this is the case for every setup

If you are only using the usdzconvert tool, I recommend you to download USDPython 0.62 because it comes not as an Apple .pkg but as the code itself. Some features are only available in newer versions (like usdzaudioimport) but in this case you would need to dig into the Apple package itself.

Another option is to convert your formats to glTF and use [usd_from_gltf](https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf)